# failed to send activation message with Mythauth

Tags: codeigniter-4

I am using myth auth to signup my website, in localhost its work but when hosting, send activation to email always display error "failed to send activation message", can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

do it like me

```
  /**
     * Resend activation account.
     * @param AuthEntity $entity
     */
    public
    function sendActivateCodeViaEmail(AuthEntity $entity): void
    {
        if (is_null($entity)) $this->httpException(lang('Shared.api.validation'), ResponseInterface::HTTP_NOT_ACCEPTABLE);

        $findUser = $this->userModel->where('email', $entity->email)
            ->where('active', 0)
            ->first();

        if (is_null($findUser)) $this->httpException(lang('Auth.activationNoUser'), ResponseInterface::HTTP_CONFLICT);


        $isSent = $this->email
            ->setTo($entity->email)
            ->setSubject(lang('Auth.activationSubject'))
            ->setMessage(view($this->authConfig->views['emailActivation'],
                ['hash' => $entity->toArray()['activate_hash']]))
            ->setMailType('html')->send();

        if (!$isSent) {


            $this->httpException(lang('Auth.unknownError'),
                ResponseInterface::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST, $this->email->printDebugger(['headers']['headers'] ?? lang('Auth.unknownError')));

        }
        unset($entity->email);


        if (!$this->userModel->update($findUser->id, $entity)) {


            $this->httpException(lang('Shared.api.reject'), ResponseInterface::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST, serializeMessages($this->userModel->errors()));

        }

    }
```

email  config

```
<?php

namespace Config;

use CodeIgniter\Config\BaseConfig;

class Email extends BaseConfig
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $fromEmail='admin@emaple.ir';

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $fromName='admin';

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $recipients;

    /**
     * The "user agent"
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $userAgent = 'CodeIgniter';

    /**
     * The mail sending protocol: mail, sendmail, smtp
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $protocol = 'smtp';

    /**
     * The server path to Sendmail.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $mailPath = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';

    /**
     * SMTP Server Address
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $SMTPHost='mail.emaple.ir';

    /**
     * SMTP Username
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $SMTPUser='admin@emaile.ir';

    /**
     * SMTP Password
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $SMTPPass='X04r0U2ikd';

    /**
     * SMTP Port
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public $SMTPPort = 25;

    /**
     * SMTP Timeout (in seconds)
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public $SMTPTimeout = 5;

    /**
     * Enable persistent SMTP connections
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $SMTPKeepAlive = false;

    /**
     * SMTP Encryption. Either tls or ssl
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $SMTPCrypto = '';

    /**
     * Enable word-wrap
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $wordWrap = true;

    /**
     * Character count to wrap at
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public $wrapChars = 76;

    /**
     * Type of mail, either 'text' or 'html'
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $mailType = 'text';

    /**
     * Character set (utf-8, iso-8859-1, etc.)
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $charset = 'UTF-8';

    /**
     * Whether to validate the email address
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $validate = false;

    /**
     * Email Priority. 1 = highest. 5 = lowest. 3 = normal
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public $priority = 3;

    /**
     * Newline character. (Use “\r\n” to comply with RFC 822)
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $CRLF = "\r\n";

    /**
     * Newline character. (Use “\r\n” to comply with RFC 822)
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $newline = "\r\n";

    /**
     * Enable BCC Batch Mode.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $BCCBatchMode = false;

    /**
     * Number of emails in each BCC batch
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public $BCCBatchSize = 200;

    /**
     * Enable notify message from server
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $DSN = false;
}
```